# Access variables in lists

Tags: r, list, select

How can I extract all the p-values from the following?

```
data(mtcars)
n<-names(mtcars)[-1]
i<-names(mtcars)[1]
ll<-lapply(n,function(x) cor.test(mtcars[[i]],mtcars[[x]],method="spearman"))
```

`lapply(ll,function(x) print(x$p.value))` - works, but is very cumbersome. There must an easier way of doing this.

Comment: You can use the function "[[": `lapply(ll, "[[", "p.value")`. The call to `print` is not needed here, all it does is print it to the console. You want your function to return `x$p.value` so you can just write `function(x) x$p.value` or `function(x) return(x$p.value)`

Comment: Thx--so direct indexing is not possible- i.e ll[[]]$p.value or something along those lines

Comment: Well I think the call to `lapply` is definitely the most natural way to do it. If you really wanted to write something else (not recommended but just for the fun of it) you could use `unlist(ll)`, which kind of collapses all the entries of `ll` into a vector. In this case it is a vector containing 70 entries, 10 for each element of `ll`, converted to character. Then you could observe that the p.values are in positions 2 + 7n (n = 1,2,..) and use `as.numeric(unlist(ll)[seq(2, length(unlist(ll)), 7)])`

Comment: (sorry that should have been "7 for each element of `ll`")

Comment: I cannot find any information on "[["--at least not using google or other search engines. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: And if I´d like to extract both the p.value and the estimate-would I have to do both lapply(ll, "[[", "p.value") & lapply(ll, "[[", "estimate")-or is it possible to do lapply(ll, "[[", c("p.value","estimate") somehow and have a dataframe returned?

Answer (score 1):

As @konvas pointed out, you can do

```
lapply(ll, "[[", "p.value")
```

to get the "p.value" element from each object in the list, but if you only want the p-value to begin with, you could do

```
sapply(n,function(x) cor.test(mtcars[[i]],mtcars[[x]],method="spearman")$p.value)
```

right from the start.

Comment: Please, *please* don’t write functions as strings. R allows this, but this is arguably an error and illogical. Functions are objects in their own right in R. No need to stringify them. \``[[`\` works just as well as `"[["` (the backticks are necessary because otherwise it’s an invalid identifier – but this is *not* a string, it’s an object name).

Comment: @KonradRudolph. But it gets passed to `match.fun` which allows character values. So yes, it is a string, but `lapply` will turn strings into functions. It is not an error or illogical, it is documented and expected.

Comment: I know what happens behind the scenes but it’s an unnecessary and illogical extra step. It’s like writing `if (x == TRUE)` instead of just `if (x)` – it has no place in a language (like R) with first-class functions. `match.fun` does more than just translating strings into functions, incidentally.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Makes sense, ` `[` ` is a function while "[" is a character. Will use the first one from now on